# Consume Azure Event Hub from Ruby

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is there a way of consuming events from Event Hubs from Ruby?

If not, how would one connect a Ruby application that needs to consume events published into Event Hubs?

e.g.: using SendGrid and a webhook? Are there more streamlined options?

Comment: Event Hubs APIs, like almost all cloud provider APIs, are HTTP. You can check the [REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/)

Comment: I checked that page before, but couldn't find anything specific about consuming events via REST. This page talks about sending events and managing event hubs, but not receiving.